# Creating connections between points in QGIS

Tags: gis, qgis

I'm relatively new to QGIS and am trying to solve a problem that is probably very simple. Essentially I have a set of points that I already have plotted in a points layer and I want to create connections between these points that represent their relationship. I also have a csv file containing the start point and end point to each connection as well as the nature of the relationship (type.a, type.b, type.c etc.). Each point has multiple connections, for example point 1 has a type a relationship with point 4 and 7, a type b relationship with point 3, a type c relationship with point 2 and no relationship with points 5 and 6. The table describing the connections looks [something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhvQM.png). What I would like to end up with is a map showing the different points and the connections between them visualised as lines which can then be customised by relationship type.

I've tried various different methods, creating a virtual layer or the points to path tool, but nothing works so far.